# How can I start a process with stdin redirected, but not stdout?

Tags: c#, winapi

I'm trying to start a subprocess with stdin redirected to a handle of my own creation, but leaving stdout and stderr pointed at the child process's console window.

Example:

```
var processStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(m_Exe)
{
    UseShellExecute = false,
    RedirectStandardInput = true,
};
m_Process = new Process {StartInfo = processStartInfo};
m_Process.Start();
m_StdIn = m_Process.StandardInput;

// write a line to the subprocess
m_StdIn.WriteLine("");
```

The problem is that setting RedirectStandardInput also causes stdout and stderr to be intercepted. If RedirectStandardInput is left unset, the output of the child process is correctly sent to the child process's console window.

Looking at the underlying win32 apis, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms686331%28v=vs.85%29.aspx says:

> If dwFlags specifies STARTF_USESTDHANDLES, this member [hStdOutput] is
>   the standard output handle for the process. Otherwise, this member is
>   ignored and the default for standard output is the console window's
>   buffer.

We have to set STARTF_USESTDHANDLES in order to redirect stdin; is there any other way to direct stdout to the console window?

Answer (score 2):

Just dont redirect standard output :

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var psi = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe")
    {
        RedirectStandardInput = true,
        RedirectStandardOutput = false,
        UseShellExecute = false
    };

    var p = new Process { StartInfo = psi };
    p.Start();

    var stdin = p.StandardInput;

    // write a line to the subprocess
    p.StandardInput.WriteLine("dir");
}
```

And the output of your process will display on Console.Out

Comment: Perhaps I should have been clearer: my master process is not a console app; when I start the subprocess it opens its own console buffer, but if you set RedirectStandardInput, the output gets swallowed (or rather, written to stdout of the master process, which in my case is invalid).

I want the output of the subprocess to go to the console window which pops up.