# C# - Write to a new Console Window

Tags: c#, .net

To write some sort of debug-extension for my applications I tried to make something that can create a new console window and write information to it.

I wrote a very simple ConsoleApplication, that basically reads the input it receives until it is equal to `terminate`.

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string text;
    while ((text = Console.ReadLine()) != "terminate")
    {
        Console.WriteLine(text);
    }
}
```

I added this ConsoleApplication to my resources and then wrote this inside a new project:

```
// Create the temporary file
string path = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), "debugprovider.exe");
File.WriteAllBytes(path, Properties.Resources.debugprovider);

// Execute the file
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
startInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
startInfo.FileName = path;

Process process = new Process();
process.StartInfo = startInfo;
process.Start();

process.StandardInput.WriteLine("Write a new line ...");
process.StandardInput.WriteLine("terminate");
process.WaitForExit();
```

When my application is closing I also call this to remove the file afterwards:

```
// Delete the temporary file as it is no longer needed
File.Delete(path);
```

My problem is that I don't see the input in the window, there only exists a blank console window. How can I fix this?

Comment: You need something like `StreamWriter myStreamWriter = process.StandardInput;  myStreamWriter.WriteLine("Write a new line..."); myStreamWriter.Close();`

Comment: Is your main project a console app as well? So you want to see the spawned console's input and output in your existing console's window? I got something like that working before as shown [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38491255/5095502), just replace `FileName` with your `path` and replace my WriteLine's with yours and it should do what you want.

Comment: @Quantic Sorry if I didn't clarify myself enough, I don't even see the input in the newly spawned window. My new project is a WPF Application.

Comment: The application has to echo the message to the Console.

Comment: @jdweng Could you explain what you mean with that? And how would I approach it?

Comment: When you send a message from main application to child process it is going into the child's standard input via a stream.  So it does't get displayed.  To see data on console it must be written to a console.  So the child process need to take every message received in standard input [ string inp =Console.ReadLine() ] and write to console  [ Console.WriteLine(inp); ]

Comment: @jdweng Look at the first code snipped in my question, ist that enough?

Comment: This is apparently a non-trivial problem. An equivalent question is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15547168/how-can-i-start-a-process-with-stdin-redirected-but-not-stdout) but there is no answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the output of your child process, then you would want to redirect standard output to and listen to the OutputDataReceived event of process:

```
process.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
process.OutputDataReceived += process_OutputDataReceived;
```

and then handled the output from your child process in process_OutputDataReceived:

```
void process_OutputDataReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e) {
    Console.Write(e.Data);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one :

```
var path = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), "debugprovider.exe");
File.WriteAllBytes(path, Properties.Resources.debugprovider);
using (var cmd = new Process())
{
    cmd.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(path)
    {
        WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden,
        UseShellExecute = false,
        RedirectStandardInput = true,
        RedirectStandardOutput = true,
        RedirectStandardError = true,
        CreateNoWindow = true
    };
    var outputStringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    cmd.OutputDataReceived += (sender, e) =>
    {
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Data))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Data);
        }
    };
    var errorStringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    cmd.ErrorDataReceived += (sender, e) =>
    {
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Data))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Data);
        }
    };
    cmd.Start();
    cmd.StandardInput.WriteLine("Write a new line ...");
    cmd.StandardInput.WriteLine("terminate");
    cmd.StandardInput.Flush();
    cmd.StandardInput.Close();
    cmd.BeginOutputReadLine();
    cmd.BeginErrorReadLine();
    cmd.WaitForExit();
}
```